# Descargar un archivo

Tags: html, windows, ubuntu, apache, bash

Tengo tres (03) computadoras con diferentes sistemas operativos. Una **MAC**, **Linux** y **Windows** y un **NAS**. Todos estos dispositivos se encuentran dentro de la misma red.

Dentro de la **NAS** tengo una carpeta compartida llamada `"master_index"` y allí un archivo **XLS** llamado `"FOR-ASC-SGC-MASTER INDEX.xls"`.

Pretendo que el usuario por medio del navegador descargue el archivo:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hola mundo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="file://192.168.1.31/master_index/FOR-ASC-SGC-004%20%20MASTER%20INDEX.xls">FOR-ASC-SGC-MASTER INDEX.xls</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Lo ejecute en **Windows** con **IE** y **Google Chrome** y lo descarga sin problemas pero cuando lo ejecuto sobre **Linux** con **Mozilla Firefox** y **Chromium** no puedo descargarlo.

¿Me pueden apoyar con este problema?

Gracias

Comment: Posiblemente estés intentando acceder a una carpeta compartida a la que no tienes acceso desde la terminal Linux. Finalmente, lo que estás haciendo es acceder a un recurso y, si el NAS dice que no tienes permiso, así hagas wget desde la consola no vas a poder.

Comment: El problema que tienes es que el enlace `file://192.168.1.31/master_index/FOR-ASC-SGC-004%20%20MASTER%20INDEX.xls` se convierte en una UNC de Windows `\\192.168.1.31\master_index\FOR-ASC-SGC-004  MASTER INDEX.xls` que, como es lógico, sólo funciona en sistemas operativos Windows. Si quieres que funcione en Windows, Linux, Android, iOS y, en general, cualquier otro dispositivo con un navegador, debes compartir el archivo mediante un protocolo estándar como HTTP o FTP, y no archivos localizados mediante [UNCs](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruta_(informática)#Uniform_Naming_Convention).

Answer (score 1):

### Esto es lo que puedes hacer

De acuerdo a lo que se pregunta y de acuerdo al código **HTML** de ejemplo presentado en el planteamiento de la pregunta, se asume que se desea descargar archivos desde un navegador Web, tal y como se haría desde una Web normal.

Para el caso de la computadora que se desee utilizar como recurso para compartir archivos deberás instalar un servidor Web (para este ejemplo se utilizará **Apache**).

#### Si la PC que utilizas como recurso tiene Linux:

Asumiendo que estás usando **Ubuntu** deberás instalarlo de esta manera, escribiendo en la terminal lo que sigue a continuación:

```sh
usuario@ubuntu~$> sudo apt install apache2
```

Si el proceso de instalación falla por problema de dependencias, ejecute el siguiente comando:

```sh
usuario@ubuntu~$> sudo apt -f install
```

Ya que con el comando anterior se le indica a `apt` que corrija las dependencias del programa en cuestión.

Una vez completado el proceso de instalación anterior proceda a crear un directorio que utilizará para compartir archivos en `/var/www/html/`. Es decir:

```sh
usuario@ubuntu~$> sudo mkdir /var/www/html/su_directorio_compartido
```

Cambie el propietario del directorio recién creado para que no tenga problemas de permisologías a la hora de copiar archivos sobre él:

```sh
usuario@ubuntu~$> sudo chown usuario@www-data /var/www/html/su_directorio_compartido
```

Cambie el permiso a `0755`:

```sh
usuario@ubuntu~$> sudo chmod 0755 /var/www/html/su_directorio_compartido
```

---

Si realizó todos estos pasos, entonces ya puede enviar sus archivos allí para que sean descargables dentro de la Red.

Ahora bien, puede crear un acceso directorio (en **Linux** es el enlace simbólico) en el **Escritorio:**

```sh
usuario@ubuntu~$> ln -s /var/www/html/su_directorio_compartido $HOME/Escritorio/su_directorio_compartido
```

Bien, ¿y cómo se accede desde otra PC al directorio `su_directorio_compartido`?

Para responder a esta pregunta primero debemos asumir que nuestro equipo tiene una dirección IP. En este caso, vamos a asumir que su dirección IP es:

```sh
192.168.1.20
```

Entonces, para acceder desde el navegador debemos introducir:

```
http://192.168.1.20/su_directorio_compartido/
```

O bien, desde un archivo **HTML:**

```html
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Hola mundo</title>
</head>
<body>
  <a href="http://192.168.1.20/su_directorio_compartido/FOR-ASC-SGC-004%20%20MASTER%20INDEX.xls">FOR-ASC-SGC-MASTER INDEX.xls</a>
</body>
```

---

#### Si la PC que utilizas como recurso tiene Windows:

Para este caso, vamos a utilizar **XAMPP**, ya que tiene incorporado por defecto **Apache**. Para empezar debemos descargar desde su [Página Oficial](https://www.apachefriends.org/es/index.html) el estalador para **Windows**.

Una vez descargado el instalador desde su Web Oficial, proceda a ejecutar su instalador y siga las instrucciones.

Completado el proceso, solo tienes que correr el programa **XAMPP** en el equipo que utilizará como recurso para compartir sus archivos.

Luego, creamos el directorio `su_directorio_compartido` en:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\
```

Una vez ubicado en `C:\xampp\htdocs\` arrastre con el botón derecho del *Mouse* el directorio `su_directorio_compartido` recién creado hacia el Escritorio y lo suelta, luego elija *Crear íconos de acceso directo aquí*

Si completó dicho proceso y la computadora tiene la dirección `192.168.1.20` podrás acceder desde el navegador escribiendo en su barra de direcciones lo que sigue:

```
http://192.168.1.20/su_directorio_compartido/
```

O desde un archivo HTML:

```html
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Hola mundo</title>
</head>
<body>
  <a href="http://192.168.1.20/su_directorio_compartido/FOR-ASC-SGC-004%20%20MASTER%20INDEX.xls">FOR-ASC-SGC-MASTER INDEX.xls</a>
</body>
```

Y para finalizar, **file** está concebido para acceder a los recursos interno de la computadora, por lo tanto, en una red no sería apropiado utilizarlo. En su lugar debería utilizarse los protocolos HTTP, FTP, SMB, entre otros para acceder a los recursos de una red. Sin embargo, para el caso de esta respuesta se utilizó el protocolo HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

Por que no usas javascript e intenta llamarlo en un evento on-click la etiqueta en la etiqueta "a" o en un botón

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
function startDownload()  
{  
     var url='http://server/folder/file.ext';    
     window.open(url, 'Download');  
}  
</script>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, estaba viendo aquí mas respuestas en stack overflow y al parecer mi error esta en el uso de file:// ya que con eso hago referencia al recurso local de windows tal vez por eso en linux no lo descarga ya que no lo encuentra. Mi NAS me ofrece el protocolo FTP pero no se como implementarlo en un botón para que lo descargue.

Comment: ohh que genial bueno estas muy bien como lo describes, animo y suerte en la próxima